# Ember Fastboot redirect to external URL

Tags: express, ember.js, ember.js-fastboot

I'm looking to 301 redirect to an external URL from within an Ember Route in Fastboot (based on the data returned by `model()`).

A solution, would be to access Express.js response object from within Ember, so I can call something like:

```
res.redirect(301, 'http://external-domain.com')?
```

However, I'm not entirely sure how `res` object can be accessed from within Ember.
Fastboot exposes a `response` object, but it's not the same as the Express `res`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will redirect both in Fastboot and in the browser:

```
if (this.get('fastboot.isFastBoot')) {
  this.get('fastboot.response.headers').set('location', 'http://google.com');
  this.set('fastboot.response.statusCode', 302);
} else {
  window.location.replaceWith('http://google.com');
}
```